# unknown tag 26 encountered bouncy castle exception

Tags: encryption, java, digital-signature, cryptography, decryption

**unknown tag 26 encountered**

at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildEncodableVector(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildDEREncodableVector(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PublicKeyFactory.createKey(Unknown Source)

Comment: unknown tag 26 encountered bouncy castle exception while decrypting the reponse xml

Comment: A little bit of context would be good.